# No default value Vs NULL Vs 0 in MySQL as a default value for text and integer fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Which is the right way to go for VARCHAR/TEXT?

In Heidi SQL and possibly in phpMyAdmin these options are provided:

1. No default value
2. Custom (where the predefined is zero like '0')
3. NULL

and the there are also timestamp, autoincrement. But these are not important now.

#### Questions

- Which from these 3 options for VARCHAR and TEXT columns should be choosen in MySQL?
- Which option for a column of type INT?

Here is a screenshot of my options:

[image]

Comment: It's entirely up to you and your needs. It depends on whether your application needs to distinguish between data that isn't entered and data that's entered with the default value.

Comment: One of the options should be more general/abstract as the others. Could you help me chose which option is the most general and safe for future extending etc.?

Comment: See the Related question links in the sidebar for more discussion of this topic. There's no general answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this simple rule of thumb:

I use `NOT NULL` for any field for which it would indicate a logical error in the system not to have supplied a value.

If telling the difference between "value not supplied" and "value supplied, but empty" then I use a field which may defaults to `NULL`.  Defaulting to `""` (or `0` for an integer field) is bad because it prevents you from making that distinction.

Comment: So, NULL is according to you beter than 0. Thanks, I was thinking the same way. But, could you help me aslo, waht is the difference between NULL and No default value?

Comment: I don't have NOT NULL in my options ;( Check the image in my post.

Comment: `NOT NULL` is a separate option from setting the default. I don't know if it exists in phpmyadmin (I've never used it), but it's in the MySQL `CREATE TABLE` syntax.